# Issue with Server Ports Not Listening

Tags: windows, port

I have a business intelligence application called Qlikview that I am trying to install on a Windows Server 2003 SP2 64-bit machine.  The application has several services that run, and they typically use ports 8081 - 8083.  Usually what happens is when you start the services, you see the server listening on the ports in netstat.  Ports 8082 & 8083 are working fine, but 8081 doesn't seem to want to listen.  I've contacted the vendor and they have never experienced this issue before.  There are no other applications trying to use the port so there are no conflicts.  Is there something on the OS level that could prevent this port from being used?  Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2):

Is there another application, like a web based application that's bound to port 8081?

for instance, I use PRTG which runs on port 81 but port 81 is only active and listed in the netstat (running with no options) output when I'm running the web based management tool in PRTG.

Try running netstat -a -n -p tcp -b and look for port 8081 in the output.

Answer (score 1):

I'm surprised that no one's said this yet: Is there a firewall getting in the way? For instance, Windows Firewall?

Comment: That's what you're here for. What took you so long? ;)

Answer (score 0):

McAfee sometimes uses this port. Here is [one reference](http://seclists.org/basics/2007/Jan/0307.html) I could find now.

Are you sure,

```
netstat -anp tcp
```

shows nothing on tcp/8081?

Comment: McAfee is not installed, so there is no conflict there.

Comment: Absolutely sure, netstat does not show anything for 8081.

Answer (score 0):

You've double-checked the "CommandCenterListenPort" value in the "C:\Program Files\QlikView\Publisher\CommandCenterService\QVPublisherCommandCenterService.exe.config" and seen that it's set to 8081? You might try setting that to another port just to see if it will listen on another port. If it doesn't listen when you try changing it to another port I'd say that something is up with the application.

(If you do change it to another port, you need to change the "CommandCenterURL" parameter in the "web.config" file in the ControlPanel folder the new port, too. Stop the "Publisher Services" before making these changes, and then restart them and ControlPanel should work, assuming that the server really does start listening on the new port.)

Comment: Someone who knows Qlikview!  I've spent hours going through all that stuff with the vendor with no luck.  I've tried using a different port but that won't listen either.  I am also inclined to think that it is an application level issue as well, but if that was the case you'd expect the vendor to be able to fix it, right?

Comment: Ugh... if you've already tried changing the port and it's still not listening then I think it's likely something up with the app. That sucks. I'd have to say that, at that point, I'd be going to the vendor... and if they can't fix it... *sigh*

Comment: Lol, ok, well thanks for taking the time to reply back.

Comment: It's worth trying an uninstall/reinstall. It wouldn't be the first time I've seen an app mangled during the installation, with no error messages of course.

Answer (score 0):

You mention that it has several services that listen on these ports.  Just a thought, but is the service that is supposed to bind to port 8081 stopping for some reason?  Or is it even really starting at all?

Answer (score 0):

If it listens on the LAN but not via WAN ensure your ISP isn't blocking that port (try portforward.com for a utility to test).